# problema con mockito + spring + jdbc template: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No Statement specified

Tags: spring, mockito, jdbc-template

Estoy tratando de hacer una prueba unitaria a un procedimiento, estoy utilizando jdbcTemplate para realizar las consultas hacias la base de datos, pero necesito que cuando este haciendo las unitarias no se conecte a la base de datos real, así que estoy usando mockito para simularlo, he buscado varios tutoriales pero no he podido solventar el problema, tengo el siguiente codigo pero no funciona.

**Clase servicio:**

```
    @Slf4j
    @Service("EjecutorService")
    public class EjecutorServiceImpl implements EjecutorService{

     @Autowired
     private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

     private SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall;


     @PostConstruct
     public void init() {
      simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate); 
    }

    @Override
    public EjecutorResponse ejecutar(EjecutorRequest request) {
     EjecutorDTO ejecutorDTO = ejecutaPrFn(request);
     log.info("despues de ejecutar ejecutorResponse: "+ejecutorResponse);
    }

    public EjecutorDTO ejecutaPrFn(EjecutorRequest request){
     String sentencia = construirSentenciaParaEnvioAProcedimiento(request);
     simpleJdbcCall.withProcedureName("poc_json_objeto1");
     SqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("IP_JSON", 
      request.sentencia).addValue("IP_MOSTRARSENTENCIAS", "n");
     Map<String, Object> out = simpleJdbcCall.execute(in);
     int opResultado = out.get("IP_IDENTIFICADOR") != null ? ((BigDecimal) 
      out.get("IP_IDENTIFICADOR")).intValue() : -1;
     java.sql.Clob clobValue = out.get("IP_RESPUESTA") != null ? (java.sql.Clob) 
     out.get("IP_RESPUESTA") : null;
     String opSalida = clobValue != null ? convierteClobAString(clobValue) : null;
     return EjecutorDTO.builder()
                      .opResultado(opResultado)
                      .opSalida(opSalida)
                      .build();
 

        }
       }
```

**cuando intento probar el método ejecutaPrFn en la prueba unitaria:**

```
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
    @SpringBootTest()
    public class otroServiceTest {

     @Autowired
     EjecutorService service;

     @Mock
     JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

     @Mock
     SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall;

     @Before
     public void init() throws SQLException {
      DatabaseMetaData databaseMetaData = mock(DatabaseMetaData.class);
      Connection con = mock(Connection.class);
      DataSource datasource = mock(DataSource.class);
      SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(datasource);
      SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCallSpy = spy(simpleJdbcCall);
      JdbcTemplate jdbc = new JdbcTemplate(new SingleConnectionDataSource(con, false));

      when(datasource.getConnection()).thenReturn(con);
      when(con.getMetaData()).thenReturn(databaseMetaData);
      when(simpleJdbcCallSpy.withCatalogName(any())).thenReturn(simpleJdbcCallSpy);
      when(simpleJdbcCallSpy.withProcedureName(any())).thenReturn(simpleJdbcCallSpy);
      when(simpleJdbcCallSpy.withSchemaName(any())).thenReturn(simpleJdbcCallSpy);
      ReflectionTestUtils.setField(service, "jdbcTemplate", jdbc);
      ReflectionTestUtils.setField(service, "simpleJdbcCall", simpleJdbcCall);
    }

    @Test
    public void prueba(){
     EjecutorRequest ejecutorRequest = new EjecutorRequest();
     ejecutorRequest.setPOwner("maikol");
     ejecutorRequest.setPPackage("lm_pck_svc_consultas");
     ejecutorRequest.setPProcedure("PRC_CSTA_MIS_SOLICITUDES");
     ejecutorRequest.setPParameters("maikol");

     // given:
     Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
     map.put("IP_IDENTIFICADOR", -21);
     map.put("IP_RESPUESTA", "<data></data>");
     // mocks:
     when(jdbcCall.execute(any(SqlParameterSource.class))).thenReturn(map);

     EjecutorResponse response = service.ejecutar(ejecutorRequest);

     assertNotNull(response);
   }
  }
```

me arroja el siguiente error:

> No Statement specified java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No Statement specified

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que tienes que tener en cuenta es que al utilizar **@SpringBootTest()** estas cargando todo el contexto de tu aplicación, por lo tanto esa anotación se utiliza para pruebas de integración y no unitarias, ahora siguiendo con esta misma idea y en base a lo que necesitas que es probar tu clase **EjecutorServiceImpl**, bastaría con anotar tu clase test solo con **@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)**, ademas recuerda anotar la clase que deseas probar con **@InjectMocks**.

Comment: De acuerdo a lo que me estas diciendo entonces la clase deberia quedar la siguiente manera:  `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
    public class otroServiceTest {

     @InjectMocks
     EjecutorService service;

     @Mock
     JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

     @Mock
     SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall;
    
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Lo que dice el compañero Ricardo es cierto, no utilices el **@SpringBootTest** ya que estarías haciendo pruebas de integración en lugar de pruebas unitarias y en tu caso no es necesario cargar el contexto de tu contenedor IOC.

O sea sí, sí es necesario, pero en el contexto de testing unitario, no de integración.

Es normal que te diga que no le mola la Statement, ya que estás utilizando un objeto mockeado en un objeto que no admite mockeos, ya que al usar una prueba de integración estás inyectando el servicio directamente, cuando lo que deberías hacer es indicarle que quieres probarlo mediante mockeo, y para ello se utiliza la anotación **@InjectMocks**

Prueba algo similar así (por cierto, las clases en java suelen comenzar en mayúscula, ya que, aunque no es imprescindible, el estándar de notación dice que hay que usar CamelCase):

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class OtroServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    EjecutorService service;

    @MockBean
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @MockBean
    SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall;

    @BeforeEach
    public void init() throws SQLException {
        DatabaseMetaData databaseMetaData = mock(DatabaseMetaData.class);
        Connection con = mock(Connection.class);
        DataSource datasource = mock(DataSource.class);
        SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(datasource);
        SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCallSpy = spy(simpleJdbcCall);
        JdbcTemplate jdbc = new JdbcTemplate(new SingleConnectionDataSource(con, false));

        when(datasource.getConnection()).thenReturn(con);
        when(con.getMetaData()).thenReturn(databaseMetaData);
        when(simpleJdbcCallSpy.withCatalogName(any())).thenReturn(simpleJdbcCallSpy);
        when(simpleJdbcCallSpy.withProcedureName(any())).thenReturn(simpleJdbcCallSpy);
        when(simpleJdbcCallSpy.withSchemaName(any())).thenReturn(simpleJdbcCallSpy);
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(service, "jdbcTemplate", jdbc);
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(service, "simpleJdbcCall", simpleJdbcCall);
    }

    @Test
    public void prueba(){
        EjecutorRequest ejecutorRequest = new EjecutorRequest();
        ejecutorRequest.setPOwner("maikol");
        ejecutorRequest.setPPackage("lm_pck_svc_consultas");
        ejecutorRequest.setPProcedure("PRC_CSTA_MIS_SOLICITUDES");
        ejecutorRequest.setPParameters("maikol");

        // given:
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("IP_IDENTIFICADOR", -21);
        map.put("IP_RESPUESTA", "<data></data>");
        // mocks:
        when(jdbcCall.execute(any(SqlParameterSource.class))).thenReturn(map);

        EjecutorResponse response = service.ejecutar(ejecutorRequest);

        assertNotNull(response);
    }
}
```

Espero te ayude.

Un saludo :)